# Gallio Integration with NANT and CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, mbunit, gallio

In our build process we're currently using MBUnit 2.x tests, called from an NAnt task, called from CruiseControl.NET.  I've uprgaded to Gallio and MBUnit 3.x locally and am able to run tests from VS2008.  I'm having trouble getting our build process upgraded.  It looks like we have two options, either run the tests from CruiseControl.net or from NAnt.  Based on this, I have two questions:

1. With all other things being equal, **where should these tests be run, NAnt or CruiseControl.net, or does it really matter at all?**
2. **If you like doing this sort of thing in NAnt, do you have any documentation or examples of how to implement it**?  I've found documentation for the CC.NET soution in my Gallio\extra\CCNet directory in the Gallio installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options for running tests as part of your build with Gallio are similar to what they were with MbUnit v2.

I recommend running the tests from your NAnt or MSBuild scripts using the provided tasks in Gallio.NAntTasks.dll and Gallio.MSBuildTasks.dll.

However, if you want to run the tests directly from the CCNet configuration, then you can add a CCNet task to execute the Gallio.Echo.exe program.

Here's a bit more info on the NAnt task that someone else blogged about.  Some of the details have changed in recent releases but it should get you on the right track.

http://testdrivendevelopment.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/use-nant-to-run-mbunit-tests-using-gallio/